# Dataset Copy, Change, then Write new Rows back

Tags: c#, database

I have this code, but I think it is too clumsy. It feels like a 12 point turn, is there a way to optimize it?

Please note that this generates new rows from existing rows.

```
//Create New Dataset
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables.Add("Temp");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("ID");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("JobNumber");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("DirectoryName");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("DrawingName");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("DateAdded");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("LastAccessedDate");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("LastAccessedUserName");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("ClientName");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("ContentType");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("Description");


//Read From Database
nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Clear();
drawing_TableTableAdapter.FillByJobNumber(nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table, OldJobcardNumber);
foreach (DataRow myRow in nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Rows)
{
    //Read from database
    string DirectoryName = myRow["DirectoryName"].ToString();
    string DrawingName = myRow["DrawingName"].ToString();
    string DateAdded = myRow["DateAdded"].ToString();
    string LastAccessedDate = myRow["LastAccessedDate"].ToString();
    string LastAccessedUserName = myRow["LastAccessedUserName"].ToString();
    string ClientName = myRow["ClientName"].ToString();
    string ContentType = myRow["ContentType"].ToString();
    string Description = myRow["Description"].ToString();

    //write to temp data table
    DataRow DrawingDataRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
    DrawingDataRow["JobNumber"] = NewJobcardNumber;
    DrawingDataRow["DirectoryName"] = DirectoryName.Replace("\\" + OldJobcardNumber + "\\", "\\" + NewJobcardNumber + "\\");
    DrawingDataRow["DrawingName"] = DrawingName;
    DrawingDataRow["DateAdded"] = DateAdded;
    DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedDate"] = LastAccessedDate;
    DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedUserName"] = LastAccessedUserName;
    DrawingDataRow["ClientName"] = ClientName;
    DrawingDataRow["ContentType"] = ContentType;
    DrawingDataRow["Description"] = Description;
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(DrawingDataRow);

}

//Refresh DataBase
nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Clear();
drawing_TableTableAdapter.Fill(nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table);

foreach (DataRow myRow in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    //read from temp data table
    string JobNumber = myRow["JobNumber"].ToString();
    string DirectoryName = myRow["DirectoryName"].ToString();
    string DrawingName = myRow["DrawingName"].ToString();
    string DateAdded = myRow["DateAdded"].ToString();
    string LastAccessedDate = myRow["LastAccessedDate"].ToString();
    string LastAccessedUserName = myRow["LastAccessedUserName"].ToString();
    string ClientName = myRow["ClientName"].ToString();
    string ContentType = myRow["ContentType"].ToString();
    string Description = myRow["Description"].ToString();

    //Write back to DataBase
    DataRow DrawingDataRow = nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.NewRow();
    DrawingDataRow["JobNumber"] = JobNumber;
    DrawingDataRow["DirectoryName"] = DirectoryName;
    DrawingDataRow["DrawingName"] = DrawingName;
    DrawingDataRow["DateAdded"] = DateAdded;
    DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedDate"] = LastAccessedDate;
    DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedUserName"] = LastAccessedUserName;
    DrawingDataRow["ClientName"] = ClientName;
    DrawingDataRow["ContentType"] = ContentType;
    DrawingDataRow["Description"] = Description;

    nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Rows.Add(DrawingDataRow);
}

myDataSet.Dispose();
//Updating
this.Validate();
drawing_TableBindingSource.EndEdit();
tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(nexusDBDataSet);
RefreshData();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you make a copy of all rows for a specific job, replace the job number and append the changed row back to the database. Sounds like this should be doable in one loop with the help of [`ItemArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and no need for a temporary table:

```
nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Clear();
drawing_TableTableAdapter.Fill(nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table);
foreach (DataRow jobRow in nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Select(string.Format("JobNumber = '{0}'", OldJobcardNumber)))
{
    var newRow = nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.NewRow();
    newRow.ItemArray = jobRow.ItemArray;

    string directoryName = jobRow["DirectoryName"].ToString();
    newRow["JobNumber"] = NewJobcardNumber;
    newRow["DirectoryName"] = DirectoryName.Replace("\\" + OldJobcardNumber + "\\", "\\" + NewJobcardNumber + "\\");

    nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
// save table
```

Comment: But could this make things slower ?,since you are filling the entire datatable?and could it create a error ware newly added rows keeps getting updated,till a stack overflow?

Comment: In your original question you were filling the entire table anyway, so there won't be a difference. I don't know how you save the data back but you can probably just fill the table by `JobNumber` and append the changed rows. Datatable's `Select` returns an array and as such won't be picking up any new rows added to the table until called again.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `DataSet` entirely and replace it with a struct/class. Then combine the read/write statements into one:

```
// do this:
DrawingDataRow["JobNumber"] = myRow.JobNumber;

//instead of this:
string JobNumber = myRow["JobNumber"].ToString();
DrawingDataRow["JobNumber"] = JobNumber;
```

So, let me see if I can avoid copy-paste errors:

```
struct Item
{
    String ID;
    String JobNumber;
    String DirectoryName;
    String DrawingName;
    String DateAdded;
    String LastAccessedDate;
    String LastAccessedUserName;
    String ClientName;
    String ContentType;
    String Description;
}
//Create New Dataset
DataSet myDataSet = new List<Item>();

//Read From Database
nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Clear();
drawing_TableTableAdapter.FillByJobNumber(nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table, OldJobcardNumber);
foreach (DataRow myRow in nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Rows)
    myDataSet.Add(new Item(){ 
        DirectoryName = myRow["DirectoryName"].ToString(),
        DrawingName = myRow["DrawingName"].ToString(),
        DateAdded = myRow["DateAdded"].ToString(),
        LastAccessedDate = myRow["LastAccessedDate"].ToString(),
        LastAccessedUserName = myRow["LastAccessedUserName"].ToString(),
        ClientName = myRow["ClientName"].ToString(),
        ContentType = myRow["ContentType"].ToString(),
        Description = myRow["Description"].ToString()
    }

//Refresh DataBase
nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Clear();
drawing_TableTableAdapter.Fill(nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table);

foreach (var myRow in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    DataRow DrawingDataRow = nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.NewRow();

    DrawingDataRow["JobNumber"]= myRow.JobNumber;
    DrawingDataRow["DirectoryName"]= myRow.DirectoryName.Replace("\\" + OldJobcardNumber + "\\", "\\" + NewJobcardNumber + "\\");
    DrawingDataRow["DrawingName"]= myRow.DrawingName;
    DrawingDataRow["DateAdded"]= myRow.DateAdded;
    DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedDate"]= myRow.LastAccessedDate;
    DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedUserName"]= myRow.LastAccessedUserName;
    DrawingDataRow["ClientName"]= myRow.ClientName;
    DrawingDataRow["ContentType"]= myRow.ContentType;
    DrawingDataRow["Description"]= myRow.Description;

    nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Rows.Add(DrawingDataRow);
}

//Updating
this.Validate();
drawing_TableBindingSource.EndEdit();
tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(nexusDBDataSet);
RefreshData();
```

Comment: I Cannot seem to get your answer to work.But Look Below for a other variation